# Flutter go_router ShellRoute builder were called multiple times when keyboard pops up

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I have a problem with the `flutter go_router` ShellRoute. Whenever I make the `TextFormField` to be focused and the keyboard pops up, the `builder` function of the ShellRoute will be called multiple times which makes me confused. What should I do to make the `builder` function to run only once?

The following are my code:

https://jihulab.com/billchen-cozy/go_router_keyboard_issue.git

**main.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

import 'debug_focus_page.dart';
import 'init_page.dart';

final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _debugNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final _router = GoRouter(debugLogDiagnostics: true, initialLocation: "/init", navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey, routes: [
  GoRoute(path: '/init', builder: (context, state) => const InitPage()),
  ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _debugNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        print('ssssss');
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: child,
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/debugFocus',
          builder: (context, state) => const DebugFocusPage(),
        )
      ])
]);

void main() {
  runApp(const HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Debug Autofocus',
      home: MaterialApp.router(
          routerConfig: _router,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ) // we can use state to change the elevation
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

**init_page.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class InitPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InitPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<InitPage> createState() => _InitPageState();
}

class _InitPageState extends State<InitPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('start debug'),
          onPressed: () {
            context.go('/debugFocus');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**debug_focus_page.dart**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DebugFocusPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DebugFocusPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DebugFocusPage> createState() => _DebugFocusPageState();
}

class _DebugFocusPageState extends State<DebugFocusPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late TextEditingController _textFieldController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
    _textFieldController.text = 'Test Debug Keyboard';
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textFieldController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('aaaa');
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _textFieldController,
        autofocus: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i am facing a similar error. whenever the keyboard is opened on a screen, it processes the '/' route multiple times. were you able to fix your error?